# python: receive indentation error for unknown reason

Tags: python

I don't understand why the following code work:

```
if trend == 1:
    maeName = tempMae.dif.idxmax()
else:
    maeName = tempMae.dif.abs().idxmin()
```

While the following code:

```
if trend == 1:
    maeValue = tempMae.dif.max()
    maeName = tempMae.dif.idxmax()
else:
    maeValue = tempMae.dif.min()
    maeName = tempMae.dif.abs().idxmin()
```

Returns error: `IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`

Comment: Please use the code sample tool.

Comment: Either you are mixing tabs with spaces (which is most likely a setting of your editor), or the whole code indentation is wrong (i.e. there is no parent block or so)

Comment: This is the error message that appears when some instructions are not correctly aligned with the other instructions of the same block. Check that there is no space or missing space. Your code as you posted it is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible you have mixed tabs and spaces. They do look alike.

Comment: I edited the question, and could notice this just from the copy-pasted code. The two lines added in the second sample are tabbed in, while everything else uses spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You may run your script with an options like this:

```
python script_file.py -tt
```

to read docs what exactly its doing you may [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-t)